# How to use laptop integrated camera to capture image?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS. I just want to capture an image with the Laptop camera and use it for object recognition. Can anyone please guide me on this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53950/how-to-use-laptop-integrated-camera-to-capture-image?/) by [Bala](https://answers.ros.org/users/4104/bala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-02-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically you just need a ROS driver for you laptop camera. Fortunately there are some generic drivers like [gscam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gscam) or [uvc_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/uvc_camera) that you could try.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-02-01**:
The driver rosnode publishes images (sensor_msgs/Image messages) on a particular topic, and then the code that you write subscribes to this topic to "capture" the image and perform whatever processing is needed to recognize the object.

**Comment by [Prashant Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22864/prashant-kumar/) on 2015-06-24**:
can you suggest how to write a subscriber and a publisher for capturing image from laptop camera?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2015-08-19**:
Hi there, the two listed packages include the publishers (you'd just need to point to the right device..). As far as the subscriber/client goes, take a look at http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm late to the party but just to help others who stumbled upon this page: use usb_cam works just as well on my laptop.

Use sudo apt-get to install usb_cam. Then you can test it with roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch

https://answers.ros.org/question/259784/use-built-in-laptop-camera-in-ros/

---

Originally posted by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) with karma: 99 on 2018-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-18**:\

> Use `sudo apt-get to install usb_cam`.

I don't believe that will work: the Debian pkgs always use dashes instead of underscores, and you're missing the name of the ROS distribution in that command.

**Comment by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) on 2018-11-18**:
Thanks for pointing this out. I just meant the user can use apt-get to install the package, not referring to the specific grammar.

**Comment by [Ankit_Jaiswal](https://answers.ros.org/users/41546/ankit_jaiswal/) on 2019-06-29**:
This doesn't work out in my case.

**Comment by [SanketKhadse](https://answers.ros.org/users/52306/sanketkhadse/) on 2020-03-06**:
Hey, as he didn't clearly specified which command to use for installing usb-cam package, use,
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-usb-cam
to install it successfully!